# GLCM on MATLAB, how to write a script to apply it on a large number of images

Tags: image, matlab, loops, glcm

I was trying the GLCM on MATLAB but I have to feed the image one by one each and that takes me forever. Is there anyway we can feed a large number of images, say 1,000 to the GLCM? How to write such loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you have n images which follow a systematic naming scheme (image1.jpg,image2.jpg,...) then it is simple:

```
for k = 1 : n
    image = imread(strcat('image',num2str(k),'.jpg'));
    %do your GLCM analysis
end
```

If they have less well formatted names, but are all stored in the same folder, then you'd have to read them using something like as follows:

```
cd DIRECTORY_IMAGES_ARE_IN;
file_list = dir;
for k = 1 : n
    image = imread(file_list(k).name);
    %GLCM code
end
```

For the worst case scenario, where your files are in a directory mixed with other things, and have no sensible naming convention, you can iterate through them using some wildcards. `dir` can take a single argument, which is the filename to look for. If you wanted to iterate over all the jpeg images in a directory, use `file_list = dir('*.jpg');`, or if the files you wanted to analyse all had 'GCLM' somewhere in them, use `file_list = dir('*GCLM*');`

Comment: Thank you very much. The image file names are actually formatted like this: EH446_20000_21000, EH446_21000_22000.

Comment: @Anh In that case I'd recommend you use the second example I posted. It looks like all your files start with a stub 'EH446', so the second line would become `file_list = dir('EH446*');`. You could then iterate `for k =1:length(file_list)`, everything else can stay the same. If I've answered your question, don't forget to accept it as an answer!

Comment: Thank you. But so with the image = imread(file_list(k).name) what should it be in for "name"? Also, after extracting the stats = graycoprops(GLCM,'all') for 8,779 images, how can I convert structure to a 8,779 x 8 matrix, i.e. 8 features extracted for 8,779 images?

Comment: @ Anh This line `image = imread(file_list(k).name);` should stay exactly as it is - it's telling matlab to iterate through the 'name' field of the file data. To write the data into one big array, add the line `data = zeros(8779,8);` outside the loop to preallocate the array, and then copy your data to `data(k)` inside the loop. I can't give you exact code without knowing more about the output of `graycoprops`, but you should be able to work it out...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still have trouble making it to report the data as 8779 arrays. My codes are like this: for k=1:8779
image = imread(strcat('EH574Sub',num2str(k),'.jpeg'));
I = rgb2gray(image);
GLCM = graycomatrix(I,'Offset',[2 0;0 2]);
stats = graycoprops(GLCM,'all')
t = struct2array(stats)
end